# iOS online High score with cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I have a simple game, and to save high-scores I wanted to do it both locally and globally. I know a bit about Game Center, but before getting into it, I was wondering if there were any other services that work well, for free, and with cocos2d?

Also is there a way to save both local and global highscores on Game-Center?

Thanks

Comment: Well you could save data by NSUserDefault

Comment: Yes, but I was asking about a global service as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Global Services that you can use. Unfortunately OpenFeint shut down just last week but there are a few alternatives that do this. Crystal, Geosophic, and Plus+ are all viable alternatives to Game Center that all have global leaderboards and work with Cocos2d. If you want help deciding which one to use, take a look at this link http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/19753 They compare the features between these different services. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will probably go with Game Center. Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial on it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12.